# AngularJS unit test error: scope is undefined

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, controller, scope, undefined

I have a problem with AngularJS unit testing. The scope in the unit test is undefined. But first the source code:

The main angular module:

```
var app = angular.module('App', [ 
    'AppCtrl',
    'AppServices',
    'AppDirectives',    
    'ngGrid',
    'ui.bootstrap',
    'angular-growl',
    'ngAnimate'
]);
```

The controller module:

```
var appCtrl = angular.module('AppCtrl', []);
```

And finally the controller to test as a simplified version:

```
appCtrl.controller('SignalListCtrl', ['$scope',  
    function($scope) { 
        $scope.name = "World";
}]);
```

Now the test. Version 1:

```
    describe("App", function () {
        beforeEach(module("App"));

        describe("SignalListCtrl", function () {
            var scope, controller;

            beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $controller) {
                scope = $rootScope.$new();
                controller = $controller("SignalListCtrl", {$scope: scope});
                //controller = $controller;
                scope.$digest();
            }));

            it("should print World", function () {
                //controller("SignalListCtrl", {$scope: scope});
                expect(scope.name).toBe("World");
            });
        });
    });
```

The error Message: `scope is undefined`.

The Version 2:

```
    describe("App", function () {
        beforeEach(module("App"));

        describe("SignalListCtrl", function () {
            var scope, controller;

            beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $controller) {
                scope = $rootScope.$new();
                //controller = $controller("SignalListCtrl", {$scope: scope});
                controller = $controller;
                scope.$digest();
            }));

            it("should print World", function () {
                controller("SignalListCtrl", {$scope: scope});
                expect(scope.name).toBe("World");
            });
        });
    });
```

The error Message: `controller is not a function`.

I use karma, if it depends on this.

This is the karma.conf from angular-seed. These are all libs that I used. I think I don't need every lib to test, so I commented this out. If everything is uncommented, the same error occurs.
edit: Every lib I use is in the karma.conf now. I get the same error messages.

```
module.exports = function(config){
    config.set({
    basePath : '../',

    files : [        
        'app/lib/jquery/jquery.js',
        'app/lib/jquery/jquery-ui-dialog.js',
        'app/lib/jquery/jquery-dialog.js',    
        'app/lib/angular/angular.js',
        'app/lib/angular/angular-*.js',
        'app/lib/angular/growl/*.js',          
        'app/lib/bootstrap/*.js',
        'app/lib/highcharts/highcharts.js',   
        'app/lib/highcharts/export.js',  
        'app/lib/xml2json/*.js', 
        'app/js/*.js',
        'test/lib/angular/angular-mocks.js',
        'test/unit/*.js'
    ],

    exclude : [
    ],

    autoWatch : true,

    frameworks: ['jasmine'],

    browsers : ['Firefox'],

    plugins : [
            'karma-junit-reporter',
            'karma-chrome-launcher',
            'karma-firefox-launcher',
            'karma-jasmine'
            ],

    junitReporter : {
      outputFile: 'test_out/unit.xml',
      suite: 'unit'
    }

})};
```

Why the scope is undefined? The scope gets the $rootScope.$new().
I hope someone can help me.

Thanks.

P.S: I asked the same question on GoogleGroups -> https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/4oAEVLbEZT4

But obviously nobody there can help me.

Comment: Could you try to add `scope.$digest()` as last line in the `beforeEach`?

Comment: Added scope.$digest(). The error messages are the same.

Comment: You're trying to load the 'App' module in your test. This App module depends on ngGrid, ui.bootstrap, etc., but the JS files defining these modules are not included in the karma files.

Comment: Every lib I use is in the karma.conf now. The same error messages.

Comment: Do you get an exception? Post the complete stack trace. Have you added console.log() traces in your code to print the values of $rootScope, scope, etc.?

Comment: I found out the error. With logLevel LOG_DEBUG in Karma (I don't know that before), I saw the message that highcharts wasn't found. Because in karma.conf the row 'app/lib/highcharts/*.js', include alphabetically 'export.js' before 'highcharts.js'. Now it works fine. Thanks to everyone.

Comment: You should not edit the code in your question to fix it. It would be better to answer your own question to share and explain, for future developpers encountering the same problem.

Answer (score 4):

try out this

```
describe("App", function () {
    beforeEach(module("App"));

    describe("SignalListCtrl", function () {
        var scope ,ctrl;

        beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $controller) {

              scope = $rootScope.$new();
            ctrl= $controller("SignalListCtrl", {$scope: scope});

        }));

        it("should print World", function () {

            expect(ctrl.name).toBe("World");
        });
    });
});
```